# Device compatibility: I made an app with scalable design.. why there are no compatible devices?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

I made an app with scalable design.. why there are no compatible devices?
In AndroidManifest I only stated permissions and the minimum sdk (2.2).

In Google Play console you can see that "493" devices you are not compatible with the apk.
How I can make it compatible with all?
I think it has to do with permissions, Could this be permissions?

For example if my app requires permissions and GPS device does not have GPS, that cause the inconsistency? What solutions are available? Since my app requires several types of permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: @ephramd Link to your app, maybe?

Comment: Is that your whole manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Tablets will not have `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` (as they have no phone state). You'll need add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" required="false/>
```

if you want your application to be compatible with those devices.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and tell you as.